# "Decade" variable ranging over 130 years - Can I treat this as continuous? I've seen it done with 8pt scales...but it doesn't past the smell test

Tags: categorical-data, continuous-data, measurement, age

My dataset includes "decade founded" but not "year founded" for organizations. I need to include some "maturity" variable in the model. Decade is the best I have. The span is 130 years, so over a dozen categories.

How do I treat *decade*?

I've enjoyed trying to find an answer. I now know a lot more about *year* variables and their treatments. But I can't find a good answer for *decade*. A colleague said I should just treat *decade* as continuous, because it has "enough" categories. I need a better rationale behind any approach I take. I'm a stickler for knowing "why" ;)

Comment: Thanks for an interesting question! Just to clarify - are you going to do some type of regression/general linear model and decade would be one of the predictors/covariates? How many observations do you have?

Comment: The number of categories (meaning, distinct possible values) is not a sufficient criterion for being continuous (or more important in your likely context -- interval scale). The number of countries is about 200 or more, but that doesn't make country even numeric. The number of children in a family is rarely more than 10 but it's fine as a quantitative variable with an interval scale. Decade is manifestly not continuous, as it's an integer (with an arbitrary origin too), but it is quantitative and interval scale.

Comment: Seems a fair question to me.

Comment: Suppose the date founded was given to the nearest microsecond -- but you have data for just 13 organizations.  How would that affect your considerations?  And if it does, what exactly is it about the difference between a decade and a microsecond that influences how you model these data?

Comment: This will generally depend on what exactly you will do with the variable. What does "treating as continuous" exactly amount to for you, and what would be your alternative, in what kind of analysis? (I'm surprised that this has already attracted four answers without this question being asked...)

Answer (score 13):

As alluded to in the comments, the word "continuous" is a a bit misleading here, and what you really care about is whether you can treat the `decade` variable as an [interval scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_of_measurement#Interval_scale) (e.g. is the difference between 1960s and 1980s the same as the difference between 1990s and 2010s?). In most situations, I would say that's a reasonable assumption to make. You could also consider recoding as `decades_ago` (e.g. 2010s = -1 decade, 2000s = -2), in which case it could also be treated as a ratio scale, since, e.g. the 1980s were twice as long ago as the 2000s.

As for continuous, no date-times are ever continuous, since they're always rounded to the decade, year, month, day, or hour, etc. The question is whether this loss of information is large enough to worry about.

Comment: I deal with ages in months frequently and it cracks me up when they're stored out to the 10th decimal place

Comment: Thanks! @AzorAhai-him-

Answer (score 6):

As the [answer by Eoin](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/629162/73129) points out, the question is not whether you have "enough categories", but whether a) time is an interval scale for your model and b) the loss of information from rounding to decade is likely to be inconsequential (i.e. if you expect only very small differences in outcome on the scale of single years or smaller). Both of those assumptions can be relaxed, if you are OK with more complex models.

The assumption of interval scale can be relaxed by fitting the effect of maturity as a smooth function (e.g. a *spline* , a *Gaussian process* or a *random walk*). This means that you assume there is some continuity over time (e.g. companies founded in 1920s will be more similar to those founded in 1930s than to those founded in 1980s). This model is more flexible and allows non-linear change over decades, but less flexible than assuming decades are completely independent (which would arise if you treated decade as a categorical predictor). There are many ready-made packages supporting spline/Gaussian process/random walk predictors.

If you assume that rounding may loose important information, you can treat the decade as *interval censored*, i.e. you assume there is some true continuous time for each observation and the decade information serves to bound the true time from both below and above.  You then can treat that "true" time as another unknown parameter and have the outcome depend on that parameter, forming a special type of a *measurement error* model. I know of no package that would have a model like that readily available (let alone one where you could combine it with spline/Gaussian process), so such a model would probably need to be implemented from scratch in some probabilistic programming language like [Stan](https://mc-stan.org/). In fact, there is a chapter in the Stan manual on [treating rounded values](https://mc-stan.org/docs/stan-users-guide/bayesian-measurement-error-model.html#rounding) as interval-censored data.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know a lot of this before. This is an excellent. I learn best when I'm learning to get a project done well.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great question, similar ones arise all the time when modeling data. For example, user ratings on a scale of 1-5 and economic data binned by quintiles. They're certainly numbers. But they're not continuous so it's not obvious.

I'll cut to the chase and suggest the following:

- if your model is susceptible to overfitting you'll most likely benefit from treating it as a single numeric feature
- if you have a lot of data and overfitting is less of a concern, I suggest starting with modeling as one feature with the decades, and 13 additional one-hot features, 1 for each decade. Then use feature selection to determine which representation is best. You may find that a few of the one-hot/indicator variables for are particularly important because of the unique (dare I say, *categorical*) social, political, and economic circumstances of those decades.

Here's why: all common models, from OLS to deep neural nets, apply continuous domain mathematical operations to your input data. All they see are floating-point numbers. Even random forests, which pick a pivot and recursively partition your data. It's the same operation regardless of whether every value is unique or 90% are 0s and 10% are 1s.

So the real question isn't whether to model your data as numeric, it's what feature vectors you should give to the model, and what their numeric values should be.

Setting aside transformations and PCA and other pre-processing steps, there are ultimately two choices:

1. one feature with the decades as numbers, as your colleague suggests. This generally makes sense when math operations on your values make sense. For example, adding 10 to the 1970s is arguably the 1980s. The 1980s are arguably halfway between the 1970s and 1990s. This representation allows the model to more easily learn long-term temporal trends in your data if they exist. "Easily" meaning less model complexity and fewer FLOPs.
2. considering the feature to be categorical and making a separate 1-hot feature for each category. This is done when math operations *don't* make sense on your data. Arguably it does not make sense to average the roaring 20's with the WW2 economy of the 1940's to get the Great Depression of the 1930's. The average of the 1970s music with 1990s music isn't 1980s hair metal. So in this case you instead want to make 1-hot vectors to indicate which decade each organization was founded in. This representation makes it easier for models to learn decade-specific behavior. A nonlinear model with enough flexibility *can* learn to isolate decades from each other from a single numeric decades feature, it will just require a more complex model and that complexity will expose you more to overfitting.

Without knowing more about your dataset and what you aim to model, there's no way to tell which is best for sure. My instinct is that treating it as a continuous numeric feature is probably the best single-feature way to use it, but it's a false choice - your model can probably accommodate an arbitrary number of features. So I encourage you to try both numeric and categorical, use some feature and model selection techniques, and find out for sure which one is best (or a combination of both).

Comment: Thanks! This is a great explanation.

Answer (score -1):

Regression on continuous variables is more difficult than classification.  However, threshold classification captures most of the information, as the above answer states.

Comment: Welcome to CV, Gregory.  An answer is not the place for comments.  If you intended to provide an answer, then please edit your post to show clearly how it does answer the question.